# trac: keep trac_auth cookie after web browser closes

Tags: trac, cookie

Is there a way to set how long the trac_auth cookie should live, so that I may stay logged in even after closing the web browser? From what I can see now, it is set to be deleted at browser exit. I use a standard installation of Trac.

Comment: Please consider accepting alexandrul's answer to make it easier for others to look for still unresolved questions. This one seems resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In `trac.ini` -> `[trac]` section:

```
auth_cookie_lifetime    Lifetime of the authentication cookie, in seconds.
    This value determines how long the browser will cache authentication information,
    and therefore, after how much inactivity a user will have to log in again.
    The default value of 0 makes the cookie expire at the end of the browsing session.
    (since 0.12)
```